# PHP POST API call

Tags: php, json, api, stream

Trying to make a POST API call and I get the error file_get_contents(http://api.turfgame.com/v4/users): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. API info can be found at http://api.turfgame.com

```
<?php
$data = array("name" => "DIProgan");

$url = 'http://api.turfgame.com/v4/users';

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
   'method'  => 'POST',
   'content' => json_encode( $data ),
   'header'=> "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
               "Accept: application/json\r\n"
   )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
$response = json_decode( $result );

var_dump($response);
?>
```

Using XAMPP & PHP 5.4.4. I tried using "requests for PHP" since I liked the Python version of it but it just complains about not finding hook functions. People seem to hate cURL and from the little I need it seemed easier without it. Maybe not. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have just created an array where you have put your parameter. It should be stored within an object first.

Comment: Yes I answered myself later on but the mods removed my answer. It should be: $data = array(array("name" => "DIProgan"));